# Events not always firing

Tags: javascript

I'm not really sure how to go with this, but here goes:

I have form elements that trigger a function (mainly for validation purposes). This triggers on click, on change etc. These are written with vanilla JavaScript.

If it's a straight-forward HTML element then everything works fine. E.g. a  element fires on change.

However, if I use a jQuery script (e.g. a jQuery colour selector), then although that jQuery script populates an  field, the validation script doesn't fire.

This I suppose is obvious as you don't click, blur, change it, it's just the jQuery script changing it.

Of course I could change the JavaScript in the colour selector jQuery script so it also fires the validation script, but there must be a better way where as well as on click, on change, on blur etc. I can also activate the function when it picks up that another script is changing it. I need this for various occasions and scripts.

Another example is a rating script (rate out of 5). It uses radio buttons as a non-jQuery fallback and the jQuery script just hides those radios (with CSS), displays the star images and then changes the radios when the user interacts with the star images. That way the server handles a form submit the same way regardless of the availability of jQuery. However, the validation script doesn't fire.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have a demo page or a fiddle?

Comment: Have you tried debugging the page with the developer console?

Comment: you can fire an event in jquery by just doing $('#something').click();

Comment: You might want to use the change event. http://api.jquery.com/change/

Comment: well, he would also need the .click/.blur events as well as other ones he uses

Answer (score 0):

Apparently  the elements are being inserted on the dom after the javascript run. 
try using $.live() instead of $.blur()

so even if this script elements are inserted after the page rendered, events will be bound to em.

http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: Hi, thanks. This seemed the most promising, but I can't get it to work. I have this demo page: http://page-test.co.uk/event.html

Comment: Seems right. the event is not fired when the property is changed.   this work, you just need to make the right selector for the inputs you want to fire the change event... http://jsfiddle.net/b8Gph/

Comment: I got really curious about this problem and started looking. 
They say here (http://help.dottoro.com/ljoiurdq.php) that on IE the event is fired just after the element loose focus... but i'v tested a bunch of times and chrome is also following this behavior.  
Change the property is not firing the event as it should. but manually changing it is. http://jsfiddle.net/H5dTH/